# Add Particular day, year, month, week in particular date using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am stuck in one query. Need your help.

I have table tblEventCalendarEvents

```
id    name      start_date   end_date    rec_type
891 Bob Lehman  2012-05-01   2099-02-01  0_2_1_1
892 Bob Lehman  2012-11-01   2099-02-01  1_4_3_1
893 Bob Lehman  2012-05-03   2099-02-01  0_0_2_2
```

I want to do such task. I want such record in which if today is `between startdate and enddate` also based on rec type.

In RecType Filed value is store like `0_2_1_1` mean this event repeat on every second month, first week and third day.

So if event start on 2012-05-01 mean 1st May, 2012 so now that event repeat on such a date which fulfill repeat condition like then it will repeat on every two month so next month is July, 1st week and 3rd day mean next repeat date is 2012-07-03 3rd July,2012.

So it will repeat on

```
2012/07/01
2012/09/02
2012/11/04
2013/01/06
```

Comment: That is going to be fearsomely fiddly, no matter which DBMS you're using. It can be done; it is not going to be fun to do.  Simply parsing the notation `month_n_w_d_#no` is messy.  It is not clear what the fields mean in the `year_n_x_y_#no` version (every nth year on the xth month and the yth day of the month?).  Your question could usefully omit the 'created_date' and `updated_date' columns as they are immaterial to the question and would avoid the horizontal scroll bar (which conceals the crucial column).  You could probably omit the 'url' column too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Now check my question again in rec_type field now data like (year_month_week_day)

it mean data will be repeated this way.
if rec_type is 0_2_1_1 then 

output data will be repeated on every 2month , first week and first day

Comment: For `0_2_1_1` it means every 2 month , first week and first day right? So in your example, it should come `2012/07/01`, `2012/09/01` etc no?

Comment: @techdo Yes something like that but in last argument mean day in that day of week not the date so it is like if 1 then sunday, 2 then Monday......n so on 7 mean saturday....

Comment: Does your question " I want such record in which if today is between startdate and enddate also based on rec type." mean that the task has to happen, if both conditions are met?

Comment: How large is this table? I am guessing, you have to process all the records everyday, right?

Comment: @Raj yes this table is more then 1k record. and i have to process all the record everyday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got my answer.

```
USE [Database]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[getNextDay]    Script Date: 12/28/2012 17:10:19 ******/

SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE function [dbo].[getNextDay](@SDate datetime, @Rec varchar(max))
returns datetime
as
BEGIN
--Find the next day based on Condition


Declare @SecArg varchar(max)
Declare @NYear varchar(max)
Declare @NMonth varchar(max)
Declare @NWeek varchar(max)
Declare @NDay varchar(max)

select @NYear = substring(@rec,0,CHARINDEX('_',@rec)) 

SET @REC = SUBSTRING(@rec,CHARINDEX('_',@rec)+1,LEN(@REC))

select @NMonth = substring(@rec,0,CHARINDEX('_',@rec)) 

SET @REC = SUBSTRING(@rec,CHARINDEX('_',@rec)+1,LEN(@REC))

select @NWeek = substring(@rec,0,CHARINDEX('_',@rec)) 

SET @REC = SUBSTRING(@rec,CHARINDEX('_',@rec)+1,LEN(@REC))

Declare @NewDate datetime
set @NewDate = @SDate
if (@NYear != 0 or @NYear != '')
begin

    set @SDate = DateAdd(Year,Convert(int,@Nyear),@SDate)
end


if (@NMonth != 0 or @NMonth != '')
begin
    set @SDate = DateAdd(Month,Convert(int,@NMonth),@SDate)
end

    return Convert(varchar, dbo.getWeekDay(Convert(int,@NWeek),Convert(Int,@rec),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@SDate)-1),@SDate)),120)
end
```

Now i Created One another function getWeekDay for find the day of particular week of particular month

```
USE [Database]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[getWeekDay]    Script Date: 12/28/2012 17:15:35 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE function [dbo].[getWeekDay]( @var_weeknum int, @var_weekday int, @var_date datetime)
returns datetime
as
BEGIN
     declare @cnt int
     declare @startDay int
     declare @DayDiffrence int 
     declare @ReturnDate datetime
     set @cnt = 1
     set @startday =  datepart(dw, dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, @var_Date),0))
     set @DayDiffrence = @var_weekday - @startday
     set @ReturnDate = dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, @var_date),0)

     if(@DayDiffrence > 0)
     begin
              set @ReturnDate = dateadd(d,@DayDiffrence,@ReturnDate)
              set @ReturnDate = dateadd(wk,@var_weeknum - 1,@ReturnDate)
     end
     else
     begin
              set @ReturnDate = dateadd(d,7 - (@DayDiffrence * -1),@ReturnDate)
              set @ReturnDate = dateadd(wk,@var_weeknum - 1,@ReturnDate)
     end

             return @ReturnDate
    end
```

Now finally i got my answer by just single query

```
 select dbo.getNextDay('2012-07-01','0_2_3_3')

 In this my date is 2012-07-01 
 my condition is every 0 year, 2 month, and 3rd week and 3rd dayofweek.

 so this will return 2012-09-18
```

Thanks to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and [blog.sqlauthority.com](http://blog.sqlauthority.com)
and also thanks to my Stackoverflow friends.... :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I highly recommend restructure (normalize) your table for the rec_type field instead of being varchar to be Four tinyint Fields as follows:
rec_y rec_m rec_w rec_d

And so simply write a User Defined Function as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetNextEvent 
(
    @curevent datetime, @rec_y tinyint, @rec_m tinyint, @rec_w tinyint, @rec_d tinyint, @end_date datetime
)
RETURNS datetime AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @nextevent datetime
    set @nextevent=DATEADD(DAY,@rec_d,DATEADD(WEEK,@rec_w,DATEADD(MONTH,@rec_m,DATEADD(YEAR,@rec_y,@curevent))))
    if @nextevent>@end_date set @nextevent=null
    RETURN @nextevent
END
```

Then you can write a Cursor loop to get all Event Dates as long as they are less than end_date based on your requirement being saved in database in another table on creation and on update or being viewed and calculated upon request.